# JavaScript Games and Security

Tags: javascript, security, logic

Let's say I'm making an HTML5 game using JavaScript and the `<canvas>` The varaibles are stored in the DOM such as `level`, `exp`, `current_map`, and the like.

Obviously, they can be edited client-side using Firebug. What would I have to do to maximize security, so it would be really hard to edit (and cheat)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store the variables in the DOM if you wish a reasonable level of security.  JavaScript, even if obfuscated, can easily be reverse engineered.  That defeats any local encryption mechanisms.

Store key variables server-side and use https to maximize security.  Even so, the client code (JavaScript) is quite vulnerable to hacking.

Comment: Get all your friends to vote but it still don't change the fact your not entirely correct :P

Comment: @Jay: The alternative I offered is to store game variables server side.  Games that store game variables client side are especially vulnerable to hacking.  I guarantee you that WoW does not store key game variables client-side for that reason (among others).

Comment: Even for caching? The question was about scoring and other details not just the final storage location...

Comment: @Jay: Defend your downvote if you think you have too, but I think you're stretching it.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion... just doesn't make it right :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.freeze` or a polyfill or a framework which does the hiding for you.

Check out http://netjs.codeplex.com/

You could also optionally implement some type of signing system but nothing is really impenetrable. For instance objects locked with `Object.freeze` or `Object.watch` can still be manually modified in memory.

What are you really trying to accomplish in the end?

What you could do is send a representation of the matrix of the game or the game itself or a special hash  or a combination of both and tally the score at the server... causing the user to not only have to modify the score but to correctly modify the state of the game.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is living in the client can be modified. That is because in MMORPG the character's data is living on the server, so players can't hack their characters using any memory tools, hex editor, etc (they actually "can", but because the server keep the correct version of the character's data is useless).

A good example was Diablo 2: you have actually two different characters: one for single player (and Network playing with other players where one was the server), and one for Battle.net. In the first case, people could "hack" the character's level and points just editing the memory on the fly or the character file with an hex editor. But that wasn't possible with the character you was using on Battle.net.

Another simple example could be a quiz where you have a limited time to answer. If you handle everything on client side, players could hack it and modify the elapsed time and always get the best score: so you need to store the timestamp on the server as well, and use that value as comparison when you get the answer.

To sum up, it doesn't matter if it's JavaScript, C++ or Assembly: the rule is always **"Don't rely on client"**. If you need security for you game data, you have to use something where the clients have no access: the server.

Answer (score 1):

**Server-side game logic**

You need to keep the sensitive data on the server and a local copy on the browser for display purposes only. Then for every action that changes these values the server should be the one responsible for verifying them. For example if the player needs to solve a puzzle you should never verify the solution client side, but take for example the hash value of the ordered pieces represented as a string and send it to the server to verify that the hash value is correct. Then increase the xp/level of the player and send the information back to the client.